# How to integrate Netsuit with Shipstation without any module?

Tags: netsuite

I try to integrate Netsuit with Shipstation without any module.

If i input Shipping information to Netsuit, Shipping data transferred from Netsuit to Shipstation automatically.

How to access Netsuit code, and also Which language should i use for that?

please give me any hint.

Answer (score 0):

The netsuite language is Javascript,

1. create a js file
2. upload into the netsuite suitescript file cabinet
3. create a script line inside netsuite
4. deploy it in test mode
5. test/update your file